# What are the keys corresponding to the shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm trying to figure out how to use my Apple keyboard at times instead of the mouse. What keys do I press for the following shortcut?

[image: Delete document menu command]

Answer (score 6):

Apple's Help menu in the finder has an article titled [What are those symbols shown in menus?](https://help.apple.com/machelp/mac/10.11/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/cpmh0011) - the related articles at the bottom are great reading. Your specific answer is:

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>

The up arrow ⇧ is the <kbd>shift</kbd> key and the symbol ⌦ is the Forward delete symbol.  Typed <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>.

Refer to [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) for further information on the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol with the X is the delete key, the up arrow is the shift key, a small up arrow (about the size of ^ ) is the control key, and the command key's symbol can be found on the keyboard above the word "command" on the key.  The [image: Option or Alt key] key is the option/alt key.

Comment: How does this improve on other answer?